# App Store Review Button

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

How can we make the "**please leave us a review in the app store**" functional PopUp in an iOS app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally used this one. I think it works really well. http://arashpayan.com/blog/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/

Answer (score 38):

It's quite easy. Create an action `rateGame` and change the id `409954448` to your app id.

```
- (IBAction)rateGame {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=409954448"]];         
}
```

This will launch the AppStore app and take the user directly to the page where s/he can rate and review your app. If you want this to happen after, say, 20 times the user loads your app, then you can add an alert in `viewDidLoad` of your main page:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
    if (launchCount == 20) {
        launchCount++;
        [prefs setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"launchCount"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LIKE MY APP?" 
                                                        message:@"Please rate it on the App Store!"
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"NO THANKS" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"RATE NOW", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];                
    }

}
```

This assumes you've set up the launchCount in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
    launchCount++;
    [prefs setInteger:launchCount  forKey:@"launchCount"];  

// YOUR CODE HERE

}
```

Comment: @WTP, I think it looks more readable for the button titles, but feel free to tone it back if you like. I don't mind edits, especially those that improve.

Comment: +1, but surely you need to tweak the developer name in your rateGame method as well? And perhaps the country code too? (Am just wondering)

Comment: @Krypton The developer name is **not** in the url. "Purple+Software" is some magic phrase that is needed to launch the correct app in the store. It's not country specific, either. Any valid app ID will work.

Answer (score 4):

There is code missing if you want user to review your app after 20 times. The missing part is

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // user hit dismiss so don't do anything
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) //review the app
    {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=409954448"]]; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, [here's one.](http://www.sysapps.com/tutorials/2011/4/18/how-to-ask-a-user-to-rate-your-application.html)

These are usually done as simple UIAlertViews with three buttons (Review Now, Later, Never) with preferences stored in NSUserDefaults to indicate whether the user has already done so, whether they never wish to be asked again, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) is also another good library to present "rate this app" dialog boxes.

Comment: iRate is a bad idea as it's not localizable.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, I will try everything out this weekend! :)

Comment: Done it with AppiRater, works like a charm, very simple also! Thank You all! :))

Comment: @WTP: iRate it is completely localizable. it exposes a variable to set each string, and you can add NSLocalizedString if you want to.

Comment: As of version 1.4, iRate is not only localizable but comes already localized to French, German, Italian, Spanish and Japanese out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10.3 iOS provides a feature for this.

```
import StoreKit
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
```

A complete class [how to request Appstore Reviews](https://github.com/MarkusWilhelm89/iOS-ask-for-appstore-reviews/blob/master/AppstoreReviewHandler.swift) can be found on my GitHubAccount.

Cheers!