# Add comments or stars to my app in iTunes

Tags: iphone, uialertview, feedback

I want to show an alert in my app so that user can either make comments or give stars to the app on iTunes.

Is it possible. ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237156/app-store-review-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the [Appirater plugin](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) for you application. This gives you the possibility to:

1. Show a popup to rate your app after a predetermined number of sessions
2. Create a button or link to send the user to the App Store page to rate the app.

Integrating the plugin is really easy, and fully documented on the GitHub website.

Let me know if this helps!

P.S. I made a localized version of the plugin through [this pull request](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/pull/6)