# how to make a rate view for my iphone game

Tags: iphone

I play lots of games where a rate view pops up and takes me right to the app store to rate the game. I want to do this for my game, too.

I've made a search on Google and found out how to know how long my app has been installed ([here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/80252-check-how-long-app-has-been-installed.html)):

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTime") 
{

      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];

      NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDate forKey:@"dateFirstLaunch"];

}
```

and then I can check with

```
NSDate *dateFirstLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dateFirstLaunch")
```

But how do I get a rate view? I've looked into the documentation but I did not see it.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You may want to check out this post: [App Store Review Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237156/app-store-review-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was recently asked here: [App Store Review Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237156/app-store-review-button/6237183#6237183)

There are many nice answers there.