# Is there a way to send a rating to the App Store without leaving the App?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way to send a rating to the app store from within my app *without* opening iTunes or the AppStore or leaving my app?

This question is not a duplicate of this question: [App Store Review Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237156/app-store-review-button/6237183) or its myriad duplicates. I know how to set up an alertView that prompts the user to rate the app and then opens the AppStore to the correct page for the user to give a rating and/or write a review.

What I would prefer to do is to pop up a view with five stars so that when the user selects a star, it and all the stars to its left are highlighted (done that). Then, if the user clicks a button entitled "Submit", the rating will be submitted to the AppStore, but the user will stay in my app. I suppose that Apple will pop up a password request, similar to what happens when updating apps. That's fine, so long as it doesn't cause the user to leave the app.

I realize that this will require an internet connection, and I know how to test for connectivity and the like, so I'm not concerned with that aspect.

Does anyone have a solution for how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot rate an app programmatically, from outside the app store. If it were possible, lots of developers would take advantage of it and would rate their apps with 5 stars without the users noticing which would defeat the purpose of a rating system. Even if a password dialog would pop up, a lot of users would not understand why it pops up and simply enter their passwords.

Comment: This action would still require user confirmation in the form of password verification from Apple, similar to what happens when you purchase or update an app, both of which are possible from within an app.

Comment: @PengOne: Imagine this: you use an app that stealthily wants to rate itself. Suddenly the password dialog pops up but you don't kno why. What would you do ? A lot of people would enter their passwords thus unknowingly rate the app. It really would be a very bad thing if Apple would make something like this possible. Anyway, we don't need to discuss the why and what, it's simply not possible as Apple has not provided a way to do that.

Comment: Yes, I agree that Apple would need to set up a mechanism to make this work. Perhaps a confirmation notice: "Rate MyApp ***?" would suffice. My question is not how Apple would prevent the system from being scammed, but whether or not they have a mechanism in place for allowing this.

Comment: They do not. All app ratings must currently go through the app store.